# Primefaces DataTable Resize Width

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I use PrimeFaces 6 's `DataTable`

```
<p:dataTable id="table">
 <p:column id="a" width="10" />
 <p:column id="b" width="100" />
 <p:column id="c" width="10" />
</p:dataTable>
```

which looks like this

```
+-----+---------------------------------------+-----+
|  a  |                   b                   |  c  |
+-----+---------------------------------------+-----+
```

I can read the column's `width` in the backing bean:

```
DataTable table = ((DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("table");
for( UIColumn col : table.getColumns()) {
    System.out.println(col.getClientId() + " = " + col.getWidth());
}
```

which results in

```
a = 10
b = 100
c = 10
```

thats fine.

Now I do a resize on column `a`:

```
+------------------------------------+----+----+
|                 a                  | b  |  c |
+------------------------------------+----+----+
```

When I now read the `width` attributes again:

```
a = 100
b = 100
c = 10
```

`a` is updated correctly, but `b` has still `100`.

Did I miss something? Or can you show me a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: How do you resize the width? Runtime?

Comment: Apart from resize on a.. do you also do resize on b? You only mentioned a..

Comment: why not set the `width` of your datatable, try it and tell us  ???

Comment: What if you  'just' use the ajax resize event?

Comment: I resize at runtime and use this: `<p:ajax event="colResize" update=":form:msgs" listener="#{dtResizableColumnsView.onResize}" />` and in the `onResize` method I read the width attributes. However `b` has the wrong width, as mentioned

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't make sense.  If you ajax update the `dataTable` it will reset to the default column widths (10,100,10).  Also, the `p:ajax` should be nested inside an `h:form` but the line `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("table")` seems to indicate the contrary.  This line also miss a closing parenthesis.  Please edit your question and provide the complete working code.

Comment: the problem still remains the same - I just simplified the question to fit to stackoverflow